# How did Ron's Ford Anglia cross the barrier between Wizarding World & Muggle World in HP Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

In *Harry Potter & The Chamber Of Secrets*, when Harry and Ron fail to cross the *9&3/4* barrier, they use their flying Ford Anglia instead to fly to Hogwarts.

It is implied that there is some sort of **barrier** between the **Muggle World and Wizarding World (at least the Hogwarts Express platform)**.

But it is unclear how they bypassed that **barrier** while flying using the Anglia. Has there been a canon explanation to this?

And how exactly did Ron know the route to Hogwarts and the train route of the Hogwarts Express (they cross their paths with Hogwarts Express in the movie) ?

Comment: As for your last question, they literally followed the Hogwarts Express.  Big steam train, after all, quite different from the Muggle trains, so easy to spot from the air.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Muggles have steam trains too.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, they're relatively rare.  Most likely there weren't any departing King's Cross at the same time as the Hogwarts Express.  Even if there was one or two, there wouldn't be so many as to make identifying the right one implausible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## You are overthinking this

They don't need to go through the 9&3/4 barrier if they're flying in the Ford Anglia. It's a wall that prevents Muggles from getting to 9&3/4, it's not some sort of wall that sections off "the entire magical world".

If you don't go by train, you never need to cross that barrier. You could also just walk to Hogwarts if you know the location and feel like walking a lot. The thing protecting it from Muggles is an illusion that makes it look like a dangerous ruin, not a magical wizarding world barrier.

Comment: Imagine a dare-devil muggle ignoring the 'dangerous ruin' signs and arriving mid-banquet in the great hall.